# copy local variable address to class pointer variable c++

Tags: c++, memory, memcpy, local-variables

I want to store some data in public pointer of class.

**like this**

```
class var
{
public:
    void *_;

    template <class T>
    var(T &t)
    {
        _ = &t;
    }
};
```

it's work fine. but if call this here is problem

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    var test = i;
    i++;
    cout << *(int *)test._;
}
```

**I want to be 1 but is 2**

**so I need to get copy of argument then if input variable changed my data not change.**

like this

```
class var
{
public:
    void *_;

    template <class T>
    var(T t)
    {
        _ = &t;
    }
};
```

so it's not working Because  ***var(T t)***  is a local variable.

so finally must be like this.

```
class var
{
public:
    void *_;

    template <class T>
    var(T t)
    {
        _ = new T;
        memcpy(_, &t, sizeof(t));
    }
};
```

that is work fine but problem is:

( ***_ = new T;*** ) this line to make memory space for memecpy take more process. like **100 times** slower.

question is:

> 1. any one know faster way then memcpy to copy local variable to pointer.
> 2. why it's take so much process time. it's a operator

Comment: There is never any reason whatsoever to use `void *` in a C++ code, except when interfacing when C libraries.

Comment: You seem to be trying to reinvent [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: yes  i want make custom any class. and with problem still faster then std::any

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to beat the writers of the standard library.

Comment: Look at the question after your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526087/c-deleting-array-of-structures-with-delete explaining why you can't use memcpy. You should use `_ = new T(t);`. Also you get a memory leak.

Comment: thanks S.M. . i use this but problem is " new " operator

Answer (score 0):

You should have a local storage for your value and a public pointer to it, I'll give an example with an union but you could do another way as proposed in comments :

```
union Value {
   int i;
   float f;
   //and so on
};

class var
{
private:
    Value mPrivateValue;
public:
    void * mPublicPointer;
    var(Value val)
    {
        mPrivateValue  = val;
        mPublicPointer = &mPrivateValue;
    }
};

int main() {
    Value val = { .i = 100 }; 
    var v(val);
    std::cout << v.mPublicPointer << "\n" << ((Value *)v.mPublicPointer)->i << "\n";
    return 0;
```

}