# C++ Deleting array of structures with delete[]

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I'm having trouble with adding structures to array in cpp. I've came up with this method which works great on ints but when i want to do the same thing on structures im getting error after adding 3 or more. I debugged it a little bit and it seems that delete[] is causing error message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I cant use vectors or list from stl so dont suggest that Here's some code:

```
struct sth
{
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
};

unsigned int id_counter = 0;
unsigned int counter_int = 0;
sth *array = new sth[0];

void print_array()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < counter_int; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << array[i].id << ' ' << array[i].name << " -- ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void add_sth(sth value)
{
    sth *newArr = new sth[counter_int + 1];
    memcpy(newArr, array, counter_int * sizeof(sth));
    delete[] array;
    array = newArr;
    array[counter_int] = value;
    ++id_counter;
    ++counter_int;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    sth e1 = {1, "abc1"};
    sth e2 = {2, "abc2"};
    add_sth(e1);
    add_sth(e2);
    add_sth(e2);

    print_array();
}
```

Comment: `memcpy(newArr, array, counter_int * sizeof(sth));` -- Undefined behavior.  The `sth` is not trivially-copyable.  Why not simply use `std::vector`?

Comment: This is the kind of thing that happens when you take too literally the idea that C++ "derives from" C - it leads you to think that you can arbitrarily _mix_ C constructs/library with C++ constructs/library.  C++ is really a different language that, for historical reasons, has a high degree of syntax and sometimes semantic compatibility with C - which can be misleading.

Comment: Replace `memcpy` with a loop that copies the array elements.

Comment: I just can't use STL, but for loop works for me. Thanks @S.M.

Comment: Better than a manual loop, use [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n). Even better, change the raw pointer to a `std::vector<sth>`.

Comment: @F.Hand *I just can't use STL* -- The `std::copy` is a function, no different than you using `memcpy`.  If you're going to use `std::string`, then get ready to use C++ functions to manipulate the struct.  Also, if you use `std::copy`, as my answer indicates, the compiler will decide for you the faster (and correct) method -- a loop, or use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably trying to copy an `std::string` with memcpy.

`std::string` is not a POD (Plain Old Data) object, and some compilers and
certainly static code analyzers e.g. SonarQube or Klocwork will alert you that
what you are doing is wrong.

To accomplish a copy correctly you should define an assignment operator and
copy the items one by one, or just use a dynamic container e.g. `std::vector`

Comment: Defining an assignment operator would not help anything here.

Comment: No an assignment operator should be defined, it is implicitly defined by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The `sth` struct has a `std::string` member, thus using `memcpy` will not work correctly due to `sth` not being trivially-copyable.  The `memcpy` function knows nothing about C++ or C++ classes that contain non-POD members.

In C++, you can replace `memcpy` with [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::copy(array, array + counter_int, newArr);
```

A good C++ compiler will transform the `std::copy` to `memcpy` if it detects that the types are trivially-copyable.  Otherwise the compiler will simply copy the objects using a loop.